# JQuery change(function()) submitting form twice

Tags: php, jquery, image-uploading

There is one "create profile" page written in PHP. There are 2 forms and 1 JQuery function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function(){   

        $('#photoimg').change(function(){ 

            $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
                        target: '#preview'
            }).submit();
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

This is where the image is displaying:

```
<div id='preview'></div>
```

**Form-1:** (For profile image uploading)

```
<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajaximage.php'>
    <input name="photoimg" id="photoimg" type="file" />
</form>
```

**Form-2:** (For other text information)

```
<form class="form-signin" name="reg" role="form" action="process.php" method="post">
    .... some normal input values ....
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**The problem:**

When I am clicking on the "photoimg" to browse image file and choose, the JQuery "onchange" is working perfectly and the "imageform" is getting submitted and 'ajaximage.php' being called the uploaded image is being showed up perfectly on the main page in the DIV 'preview' without refreshing the main page. This portion is working perfectly.

Now after that if I click on SUBMIT button of Form "reg", instead of going to "process.php" it is again going to "ajaximage.php". This is the problem.

If I REFRESH the main page and then click on SUBMIT button of Form "reg", then it will go to "process.php".

I am not sure if my question is clear. Thanks in advance for your time & help.

Adding the "ajaximage.php" code for your reference:

```
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
 .......
  do all the image upload stuff & update database
 .......
 echo "<img src='uploads/".$actual_image_name."'>";
}
```

Comment: Your question is very clear..

Comment: I've tried your code in my localhost.. and it's working like a charm.. when I browse image file, jQuery .change event is working and can see ajaximage.php called in browser console and when I click on submit, page is redirected to process.php, without refreshing the page!!

Comment: did you try ajaxSubmit()..

Comment: @Shaunak: I have added the ajaximage.php code format. Try again please.

Comment: @ParthaMitra: It's working as well.. I've kept mine file upload code where you've written `.......
  do all the image upload stuff & update database
 .......` and I found it's working.. I can get uploaded image in folder and on screen without refreshing page on change event of `photoimg`, immediately I fill the text box of `reg` form and submitted, I got process.php page...

Answer (score 0):

Possible walk through.

1. Check if all the html tags are properly closed after your target div is updated.
2. Try to focus out of file element after completion of request.
3. Check for jQuery errors on your console.
4. Check if some ids are not conflicting.